# Jekyll issues with nested looping over a collection's subdirectories

Tags: for-loop, jekyll, liquid, templating

Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

I am trying to create a nested navigation for a collection, `d-foundation`. I want to base the structure of the nested nav off the directory structure, instead of manually creating a Yaml file since I want it to be as dynamic as possible. The abbreviated version of my directory structure looks like this:

```
|-Root/
|-d-foundation/
|--|-color.md
|--|-headings.md
|--|-formats.md
|--|--formats/
|--|--|-date.md
|--|--|-time.md
```

I am putting front matter in the `.md` files to specify if the file is a parent or child, or not including either of those properties if the file is not associated with anything.

Parent in this example is `formats.md` in the root of `d-foundation`:

```
---
parent: true
parent-name: foo
---
```

Child/ children are in the `formats` directory with the properties:

```
---
child-of: foo
---
```

Then, I attempt to first loop over the top-level files, detect if a file is a parent, and then loop over the subsequent child files:

```
<ul class="design-subnav">
   {% for foundation in site.d-foundation %}
   {% if foundation.child-of == nil and foundation.parent == nil %} 
   <li><a href="{{ foundation.url }}">{{ foundation.title }}</a></li>
   {% endif %}

   {% if foundation.parent != nil %}
   <li><span>{{ foundation.title }}</span>
         <ul>
            {% for child in site.d-foundation %}
            {% if child.child-of != nil %}
             <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %} 
         </ul>
    </li>
    {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I know [one of] my problem lies in the fact I'm not limiting the loop's scope to each parent (can you do that?). The result is that if I were to have several subdirectories, the second for loop would simply print out any file with the `child-of` property. Seen here, the items indented the furthest are children, and you can see the duplication:

[A screen shot showing the loop iterating over any children in the collection, not just limited to a parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrYJn.png)

The only reason the top section isn't duplicating children is that I only have one parent/subdirectory.

I've gotten myself tangled up here and I'm wondering what I can do to only loop over each parent's respective children. Or am I going about this in a completely backwards way?

Comment: I think it would resolve it if you change the inner `if` statement with `{% if child.child-of == foundation.parent %}`

Comment: @marcanuy That was it! Thank you so much.

Comment: You’re welcome, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner `if` with `{% if child.child-of == foundation.parent %}` to filter each category with their subcategories.

So it would look like:

```
<ul class="design-subnav">
   {% for foundation in site.d-foundation %}
   {% if foundation.child-of == nil and foundation.parent == nil %} 
   <li><a href="{{ foundation.url }}">{{ foundation.title }}</a></li>
   {% endif %}

   {% if foundation.parent != nil %}
   <li><span>{{ foundation.title }}</span>
         <ul>
            {% for child in site.d-foundation %}
            {% if child.child-of == foundation.parent %}
             <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %} 
         </ul>
    </li>
    {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Side note**: All values in Liquid are truthy except *nil* and *false*. So you can use `if foundation.child-of` instead of `if foundation.child-of != nil`.

Comment: Ah, noted. Thanks for the clarification.